# react-router dynamic routing instead of pattern matching

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My client has specific SEO/URL requirements, I'm trying to figure out how to make this work with react-router.

How can a set of URLs matching the same pattern, be declared to use different Handlers?

e.g. /A is HandlerA but /B is HandlerB and /B/C is HandlerA also, where there are many permutations (dynamic at run-time) that must be catered for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming global RouteTable holds all the data needed to make the decision, it turns out this can be done in advance of the `<Route>` object being constructed:

```
var routes = RouteTable.map(r => {
    if (some logic) {
        return (<Route handler={A} name={r.url} path={r.url} />);
    } else {
        return (<Route handler={B} name={r.url} path={r.url} />);
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Route path='/'>
        {routes}
    </Route>
);
```

and then all `<Links>` are just done with URL, e.g. `<Link to={url}>...`

Comment: note that the `r =>` syntax is just ECMAScript 6 for `function(r)`